# Long polling in Django - can't get page to update

Tags: ajax, django

I'm new to Django so apologies if this is a really stupid question but I'm trying to get a table to reload database values and when I open the page in a browser it loads ok initially but when it tries to reload nothing appears to happen.  When I look in the network section of inspect element I can see repeated 404 page not found errors.  I've been searching stack exchange etc. for a few days and I've tried various types of quotes etc. round the url tag but no joy.  I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give me on this.  I'm using python 3 and django2.

Project level urls.py

[project level urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eMie.png)

App Level urls.py

[App level urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K9Po.png)

App views
[App views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXOmY.png)

HTML
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPb3t.png)

Directory Structure
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Sru.png)

Terminal 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxqXp.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be the case next page will not have any data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The page should just be re-loading itself again(if that's the correct way to word it) so even if there aren't any new records in the database the same ones should be shown again.  If I add new records they also don't show up.

Comment: This is what it says in the terminal where the server is running - sorry, just realised that I can't add images here,  I'll put the terminal output above also

Comment: are you using pagination, please share the code

Comment: No, no pagination.  It's just a really small project to test out a concept.  Thanks

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures. Post the code here, as text.

Comment: Will do.  I couldn't get the formatting to come out right and it looked difficult to read but I'll try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo: you have a space between the `{` and the `%` in your url tag. This is causing Django to not recognise it as a tag, so the Ajax is using the literal string "{ % url ... }" as the URL which explains the mess you see in the terminal. Remove the space.

(Note, you still might not get the result you expect, since your Ajax function returns a complete HTML page but you are inserting that result inside a div in an existing page; you probably either want to replace the whole page or return a template fragment from your view.)

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much,  can't believe it was something so simple.  I did get another error when I changed that but I'll your other suggestion now.